# Implement a Delphi interface using an 'anonymous' class

Tags: delphi

I have an interface.

```
type IProgressObserver = interface(IInterface)
    procedure ReportProgress(Progress:Integer);
    procedure ReportError(Message:string);
end;
```

I have implemented the interface using a named class, as follows:

```
type TProgressObserver=class(TInterfacedObject, IProgressObserver)    
    procedure ReportProgress(Progress:Integer);
    procedure ReportError(Message:string);
end;

... implementation of methods go here .....

addProgressObserver(TProgressObserver.Create);
```

Is it possible to create an instance of this interface without declaring a class? Something like this (imaginary) code, that would do the same thing as above:

```
 addProgressObserver(IProgressObserver.Create()
 begin
   procedure ReportProgress(Progress:Integer)
   begin
     ShowMessage('Progress Observed!');
   end

   procedure ReportError(Message:string)
   begin
     Log(Message);
   end
 end;);
```

Delphi has anonymous procedures, but does it have anonymous classes??

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184445/anonymous-class-definition-based-on-interface-maybe), but it's in Java.

I am using Delphi 2010

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You *can* get pretty anonymous, implementing the interface using anonymous methods. But you don't get actual compiler support for this, you'll have to declare all the anonymous method types yourself, then implement the actual "anonymous" class. Given your `IProgressObserver` interface, the implementation would look something like this:

```
type
  // This is the interface we'll be dealing with.
  IProgressObserver = interface(IInterface)
    procedure ReportProgress(Progress:Integer);
    procedure ReportError(Message:string);
  end;

  // This will help us anonymously create implementations of the IProgressObserver
  // interface.
  TAnonymousObserverImp = class(TInterfacedObject, IProgressObserver)
  type
    // Declare reference types for all the methods the interface needs.
    TReportProgressProc = reference to procedure(Progress:Integer);
    TReportErrorProc = reference to procedure(Message:string);
  strict private
    FReportProgressProc: TReportProgressProc;
    FReportErrorProc: TReportErrorProc;

    // Actual implementation of interface methods.
    procedure ReportProgress(Progress:Integer);
    procedure ReportError(Message:string);
    // private constructor, so we'll forced to use the public "Construct" function
    constructor Create(aReportProgressProc: TReportProgressProc; aReportErrorProc: TReportErrorProc);
  public
    // This takes the required anonymous methods as parameters and constructs an anonymous implementation
    // of the IProgressObserver interface.
    class function Construct(aReportProgressProc: TReportProgressProc; aReportErrorProc: TReportErrorProc): IProgressObserver;
  end;

{ TAnonymousObserverImp }

class function TAnonymousObserverImp.Construct(
  aReportProgressProc: TReportProgressProc;
  aReportErrorProc: TReportErrorProc): IProgressObserver;
begin
  // Call the private constructor
  Result := TAnonymousObserverImp.Create(aReportProgressProc, aReportErrorProc);
end;

constructor TAnonymousObserverImp.Create(
  aReportProgressProc: TReportProgressProc; aReportErrorProc: TReportErrorProc);
begin
  inherited Create;
  // We simply save the references for later use
  FReportProgressProc := aReportProgressProc;
  FReportErrorProc := aReportErrorProc;
end;

procedure TAnonymousObserverImp.ReportError(Message: string);
begin
  // Delegate to anonymous method
  FReportErrorProc(Message);
end;

procedure TAnonymousObserverImp.ReportProgress(Progress: Integer);
begin
  // Delegate to anonymous method
  FReportProgressProc(Progress);
end;
```

Once all that code is in place you'll be able to write code like this:

```
var i: IProgressObserver;
begin
  i := TAnonymousObserverImp.Construct(
    procedure (Progress:Integer)
    begin
      // Do something with Progress
    end
    ,
    procedure (Message:string)
    begin
      // Do something with Message
    end
  )
end;
```

Looks pretty anonymous to me! Given the implementation of anonymous methods in Delphi it's also fairly fast and effective.

Comment: Wow! Great answer (assuming it works that is.. I haven't tested it). Of course, it's a lot more code if you are only creating an instance once (which I am). In my case it's a lot easier to just create a named class, but if you are writing a 3rd party library used by millions of programmers, this would be the way to go. I wonder if all that boilerplate could be auto-generated?

Comment: @awmross, of course it works, I test my code before posting it! Automating boilerplate-generation shouldn't be much of a problem, but it'd be better if the compiler did it.

Comment: Whilst this is certainly clever, I'm struggling to see when this would be particularly useful.

Comment: @ David It would (well.. *could*) be useful if your were writing a 3rd party library that used interfaces. You write this code once, saves all the users of your library a lot of pain (potentially)

Comment: @Cosmin No offence intended! I was just making it clear to others that I hadn't actually run the code myself, even though I was calling it a "great answer" :-)

Comment: @David, I'm using something like this to implement enumerators, and it's very handy. The VCL itself does the same in `TDelegatedComparer<T>`, and I'm sure there are other examples.

Comment: @awmross I don't find it painful to implement interfaces. Where is the pain?

Comment: @David, there is some pain, especially for smallish interfaces like OP's sample: you need to declare a class and a few methods+implementation, and none of that can be local to the procedure that actually needs the interface instance. Using such anonymous implementations keeps the implementation where it's logically needed and doesn't pollute the namespace. I'll give the `TDelegatedComparer<T>` example again: Boy did I hate the global functions required for pre-generics `TList.Sort()` calls!

Comment: @David. What Cosmin said. It's painful when you have small interfaces that don't do much. With anonymous classes, you just write the code to implement the interface right where you are using it, then keep on coding. With named classes, you have to stop, navigate to the interface section, write the class declaration, navigate to the implementation section, write your code *there* (instead of where it's actually used), then go back to what you were originally doing... if you still remember what it was. And what Cosmin said about polluting the namespace...

Comment: @awmross You don't need to define a class in the interface section. I regularly define them in the implementation section right next to the routine that uses them. Indirection is very powerful but has a cost in terms of clarity. You need to weigh that trade off and the preferred option is not necessarily always the same.

Comment: @David You are right about the implementation section. My main point was that you still have to write separate header and implementations (which is the 'pain' I was referring to), even if the header is in the implementation section rather than the interface section.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer I'm afraid: sorry, no, Delphi doesn't have anonymous classes.

Comment: Although it looks like Prism does: http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en-w/index.php?title=Anonymous_Types&oldid=21059

Comment: Prism is not Delphi